# How Can i Integrate func with puppet?

Tags: puppet, func

how do i integrate func (fedora unified network controller) and puppet?
The documentation of func itself is not updated since 2 years.
Any help be appreciated.

https://fedorahosted.org/func/

Thanks
-Aditya

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that. If you are really good on it, you can work by yourself and put in Github or Forge to share with others.

But for starting, you can search in forge first, maybe someone have worked on it, and have the solutions already.

So here they are:

[razorsedge/func](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/razorsedge/func)

[rodjek/func](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/rodjek/func)

Comment: Hi there, i think u got me wrong..i do not want to install func using puppet rather i want to use puppet client as func clients or minions...there is a provision of using puppet certificates with func..but had no idea about it, and documentation steps are not working for me..